# 'undefined' when trying to read from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using an API to get balance in a bitcoin address.

My code is:

```
async function getWalletBalance(address) {
    try {
        const response = await got(`blockchain.info/balance?active=${address}`)
        return response.body.address.final_balance
    } catch(err) {
        return err
    }
}
```

The returning JSON is:

```
{
  "3D2oetdNuZUqQHPJmcMDDHYoqkyNVsFk9r": {
    "final_balance": 15392048444281,
    "n_tx": 3938,
    "total_received": 138450271881712
  }
}
```

But when I try to read the final balance, it gives me undefined. How do I fix this?

Comment: `.body[address]`, not `.body.address`.

Comment: there is no `address` in the JSON, instead you have an actual address which is `3D2oetdNuZUqQHPJmcMDDHYoqkyNVsFk9r`

Answer (score 2):

`response.body.address.final_balance` is looking for the literal key `address`, not looking for the key `3D2oetdNuZUqQHPJmcMDDHYoqkyNVsFk9r` in your example.

Using `response.body[address].final_balance` instead should fix your problem.

The snippet below is slightly modified (and doesn't have a call to get a real response) but should do the job.

```js
function getWalletBalance(address) {
    try {
        const body = {
          "3D2oetdNuZUqQHPJmcMDDHYoqkyNVsFk9r": {
            "final_balance": 15392048444281,
            "n_tx": 3938,
            "total_received": 138450271881712
          }
        };
        console.log('using body[address]:', body[address].final_balance);
    } catch(err) {
        return err
    }
}

getWalletBalance("3D2oetdNuZUqQHPJmcMDDHYoqkyNVsFk9r");
```

Comment: Still returning `undefined`.

Comment: Added a snippet that you can run and look at.

Comment: Still not working. I don't understand what I've done wrong.

Comment: At what part of your access does it return undefined? It should be pretty easy to figure out what your object looks like with a debugger (or just console logging if you're not familiar). Are you sure response isn't undefined? If it's there, can you access response.body? If yes, try response.body[address], and so on until you find exactly where the problem is.

Comment: console logging response.body works fine, but as soon as I try to access [address], it immediately returns undefined. I even tried hard coding the address and it still didn't work.

Comment: response.body returns exactly the JSON you posted in your original question? When using response.body[address], are you sure address refers to a string? Same question for when you hardcoded it.